# What is wrong in this approach?

Tags: probability

I was trying to solve :([sixteen players $s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots, s_{16}$ playing a tournament are divided into eight pairs at random](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618014/sixteen-players-s-1-s-2-s-3-ldots-s-16-playing-a-tournament-are-divided))

Sixteen players $s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots, s_{16}$ playing a tournament are divided into eight pairs at random.  From each pair, a winner is decided on the basis of a game played between the two players of the pair.  Assume all players are of equal strength.

1. Find the probability that $s_1$ is among the eight winners.
2. Find the probability that exactly one of the players $s_1$ and $s_2$ are present in the $8$ winners.

I tried to solve the second part using the classical approach:

**Favourable outcomes**: If the first player wins the second has to lose and vice versa. There are 2 ways to select one of the two players as winner. Now, 14 players can play against $s_1$ and remaining 13 against $s_2$, $s_1$ wins and $s_2$ loses in one way. Also, if $s_1$ and $s_2$ play together both the outcomes are favourable, so total number of *favourable outcomes*= $2*14*13+2$

Similarly, *total outcomes*$=4*14*13 +2$, where 4 comes because 
there are 4 outcomes for the two matches.

The answer I get is incorrect, please tell me where I went wrong. I hope my explanation is not too confusing.

Comment: I think your issue might be from the fact that in the 2*14*13 term, you are considering the outcomes of 2 matches (one involving each of the first two players) whereas in the +2 term, you're only considering the outcome of 1 match. That is to say, your sample space is not consistent across the calculation, which gets you the wrong answer.

Comment: What are you calling an "outcome"?  If you just mean a selection of winners, well that's $\binom {16}8=12870$.  Please be clear as to your definitions...problems like this generally come down to lack of precision in the basic terms.

Comment: FullBridge,   your method gives $\frac{2*14*13+2}{4*14*13+2}$.  The correct method gives  $\frac{2*14*13+4*13}{4*14*13+4*13}=8/15$.  This is because it is 14 times less likely that player 1 will face player 2.   Also, when they face each other, every one of the 4 possible outcomes for the first two games is favorable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take the probabilities of the different events into account

- The probability $s_1$ and $s_2$ are matched together is $\frac{1}{15}$ and that they are not is $\frac{14}{15}$
- If they are together then the conditional probability exactly one is a winner is $1$
- If they are not together then the conditional probability exactly one is a winner is $\frac12$

So the answer is $\frac1{15}\times 1 +\frac{14}{15}\times \frac12 = \frac{8}{15}$

If you want to count equally probable events, then you could say (treating the matches as played consecutively) that

- there are $\frac{16!}{(2!)^8}2^8 = 16!$ ways of ordering the matches with one winner from each
- $16 \times 14!$ have $s_1$ and $s_2$ matched together; all will have one as a winner
- $16 \times 14 \times 14!$ have $s_1$ and $s_2$ in different matches; of these $4 \times 14 \times 14!$ have $s_1$ winning but $s_2$ not, while $4 \times 14 \times 14!$ have $s_2$ winning but $s_1$ not

So if you took this and tried to translate it into the format of your answer, e.g. by dividing by $14!$ and rearranging, you would get $\frac{2 \times 4 \times 14+16}{4 \times 4 \times 14+16} = \frac{8}{15}$ again.

Your answer severely understates the likelihood of the two players being matched together, implicitly using $\frac{2}{4\times 14 \times 13 +2} = \frac{1}{365}$ rather than the correct $\frac{1}{15}$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not "promising" for the reason given in the first comment.
Better to change it, and consider that each player has fifty-fifty chance to win /loose.
So everything boils down to place a binary string with $8$ ones and $8$ zeros.
With this scheme it is easy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is you're counting things weirdly. When you consider different "ways" of doing something, those different ways all have to have an equal chance of occurring.

If I asked you, "What is the chance I don't roll a '1' with this die?", then one way of working it out would be to say "Well, I can either roll an even number, a 3, or a 5, so there are 3 favourable outcomes". That is obviously *incorrect* logic.

Similarly, in this question, you need to make sure your outcomes have equal chances. For instance, if $s_1$ and $s_2$ are paired, there are $\frac{14!}{(2!)^7}$ ways of rearranging the other players, whereas if $s_1$ and $s_2$ are unpaired, there are $\frac{12!}{(2!)^6}$ ways of rearranging the other players. These numbers are clearly different.